# Typescript type for custom Record keys

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, record

I am trying to write a small library where I want to add type safety to the following object:

```
export const ErrorCodeMap: Record<string, [string, number]> = {
  NOT_FOUND: ['1001', 222],
  ALREADY_EXISTS: ['1002', 111],
}
```

Now what I want to do is to get a type-safe list of the keys of the object `ErrorCodeMap`.

If I do the following

```
export type ErrorCode = keyof typeof ErrorCodeMap;
```

the type of `ErrorCode` is equal to `string`. I would like it to equal `'NOT_FOUND' | 'ALREADY_EXISTS'`.

I tried to use the `as const` synthax but I think I am a bit off here.

Is there any way to solve this WITHOUT removing the `Record<string, [string, number]>` definition and thus retaining type safety on the object definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach gives you a suitable type...

```js
export const ERROR_MAP = {
  NOT_FOUND: ['1001', 222],
  ALREADY_EXISTS: ['1002', 111],
} as const satisfies Record<string, readonly [string, number]>

// hover to reveal type ErrorCode = "NOT_FOUND" | "ALREADY_EXISTS"
type ErrorCode = keyof typeof ERROR_MAP;
```

[Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NV38nm)

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the fast reply! This requires the latest version of Typescript 4.9 as far as I can see and it seems to break ESLint, though from what I see it works, which is just what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: The use of satisfies (as per https://medium.com/@cefn/typescript-satisfies-6ba52e74cb2f ) is a bonus. Before 4.9 you would get the error a long way from the place the actual error was (e.g. when you tried to use ERROR_MAP['NOT_FOUND'] somewhere and it turned out not to be a tuple). This helps to localise the issue. If your case is pre-4.9, you could probably remove everything from satisfies onwards and it would work the same.

Comment: Up-to-date Eslint and Prettier should now be compatible with 4.9 and satisfies.

Comment: Nice using `satisfies` :)